# Changing the $HOME environment variable in terminal on mac 10.8

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables

To be clear im not looking for a workaround that will execute a change directory command on startup. I want to alter the $HOME env var so that tilde commands work and so that entering a 'cd' command will return me to that directory.

I am sure it is possible I am just not able to find the command.

I have tried setting it in my /etc/profile but it doesnt seem to work. I have tried about 4 different settings in there. The ones I can remember trying are:

```
$HOME = /directroy
$HOME = "/directroy"
setenv HOME /directory
```

I may be missing something simple but I'm unable to find a solution.

Comment: Actually I wonder more why HOME is not already set correctly when the shell starts. If you open a new tab in Terminal, what is the result of `echo $HOME`?

Comment: @patrix I probably should have been more descriptive. It is "correctly" set to my user's home directory. I would like it to be a different directory as all of my terminal use is based out of another directory.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend against doing that. The convention that $HOME points to your home directory is strongly embedded in Unix space and lot of shell scripts, perl scripts, binaries rely on that. You will get better results by defining something like `MYROOT=/Users/andrew/base/of/all/things` and then use `$MYROOT` where appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash (the default shell of Terminal on 10.8) the syntax:

```
HOME=/your/path
export HOME
```

Comment: This only worked for my current session. Opening a new terminal would have HOME reset back to its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @patrix comment, change your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file to add the following lines:

```
MYROOT=/path/to/dir/you/want
export MYROOT
cd $MYROOT
```

This way you will get you will start your shell in `/path/to/dir/you/want` and using `cd $MYROOT` will bring you back there.